# SSH: A javac command that works in terminal doesn't work when executed over SSH

Tags: python, hadoop, ssh, javac, cloudera

I'm using Python code to run a Hadoop program on a Linux (Cloudera) machine using SSH.

I'm having some trouble with compiling java files to class files. When I'm executing the command:
`javac -cp  /usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/* remote_hadoop/javasrc/*` from the Linux terminal all the files get compiled successfully.

When I'm executing the same command through my Python SSH client I'm receiving an 'invalid flag' error:

spur.results.RunProcessError: return code: 2
output: b''
stderr output: b'javac: invalid flag: remote_hadoop/javasrc\nUsage: javac  \nuse -help for a list of possible options\n'

The python code:

```
list_of_commands = ["javac", "-cp", r"/usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*", input_folder + r"/*"]
print ' '.join(list_of_commands)
self.shell.run(list_of_commands)
```

The command is getting rendered correctly, since what is getting printed is `javac -cp /usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*  remote_hadoop/javasrc/*`.

**UPDATE:** It's pretty weird. I can compile one file at a time over ssh, but not all of them. Seems like something happens to the "*" over ssh.

Comment: What is `self.shell.run`? Commands must be strings by the time they hit ssh, so it's got to be doing some conversion, but not necessarily the same conversion you applied. If it displays results coming back, you could try `["echo", "javac", "-cp", r"/usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*", input_folder + r"/*"]` or even save it on the remote side `["echo", "javac", "-cp", r"/usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*", input_folder + r"/*", ">/tmp/trace.txt"]`. Your ssh may have a debug level you can set for more details.

Comment: self.shell is a spur.SshShell object.

Comment: It's pretty weird. I can compile one file at a time over ssh, but not all of them. Seems like something happens to the "*" over ssh.

Comment: Why are you collecting commands in an array, then throwing away that data by joining them with a string rather than shell-escaping? You're not getting argv-equivalent behavior; for that, you'd want to use `shlex.quote()` on the individual elements before joining on Python 3, or `pipes.quote()` on Python 2.

Comment: It's not that something happens to the `*` over ssh, but that something happens to the `*` *whenever you're not using ssh*; when you have a shell in place, the argument with the glob expression that successfully matches files is removed from the command line and replaced with a filenames that it is able to successfully match before `javac` is actually started.

Comment: Mind you, normally, there's a remote shell parsing step SSH is in use also, but it looks like your Python library is automatically doing escaping to effectively suppress that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a list of arguments, not a list of commands. It's not even an *accurate* list of arguments.

If your underlying tool expects a list of arguments, then pass:

```
['sh', '-c', 'javac -cp /usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*  remote_hadoop/javasrc/*']
```

If it expects a list of commands:

```
['javac -cp /usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*  remote_hadoop/javasrc/*']
```

If it expects something else -- read the documentation and determine what that something is!

---

Note that SSH doesn't provide a way to pass a literal argv array when running an arbitrary command; rather, it expects -- at the protocol level -- a string ready for parsing by the remote shell. If your `self.shell.run` code is doing shell quoting before joining the argument list given, then it would be passing the last argument as the **literal string** `remote_hadoop/javasrc/*` -- **not expanding it into a list of filenames as a shell would**.

Using the `sh -c` form forces the remote shell to perform expansion on its end, assuming that contents are being given to it in a form which doesn't have remote expansion performed already.

Comment: Thanks :). Passing ['sh', '-c', 'javac -cp /usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/client-0.20/*  remote_hadoop/javasrc/*'] did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the way that `spur` builds the command list into a command string. It takes every command token and encloses it in single quotes (`["ls", "*.txt"])` becomes `'ls' '*.txt'`). There is no shell expansion of `*` inside quotes, so the command doesn't work.

You can see the problem in spur's [ssh.py](https://github.com/mwilliamson/spur.py/blob/master/spur/ssh.py) on line 323:

```
def escape_sh(value):
    return "'" + value.replace("'", "'\\''") + "'"
```

I don't use spur, but it looks like it just doesn't allow you to do such things. The problem with "simplifiers" like spur is that if they simplify in a way you don't want, you can't use them.